# Why is this shown as error and what is it supposed to be?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

It's part of a game.
The game reads the map file and now the map has to be implemented in singleton design pattern. if() is shown as error in compiler.
I have the code below:

```
//.h
class Map
{
    static Map* m_instance;
public:
    static Map* getInstance();
    Map();
    ~Map();

//.cpp
static Map *getInstance()
{
    if (!m_instance)
        m_instance = new Map();
    return m_instance;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You don't close the class declaration with `};` at the end.

Comment: Your `getInstance()` definition is a free function, not a member of `Map`, and has no variable `m_instance`. I you're trying to implement the member function, you need `static Map *Map::getInstance()`

Comment: After the word "error" there should be text describing the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `Map` static instance declared in the cpp file?

```
// Map.h
class Map {
  static Map *m_instance;
public:
  static Map *getInstance();
  Map() = default;
  ~Map() = default;
};
```

```
// Map.cpp
Map *Map::m_instance = nullptr; // <--- this line?

Map *Map::getInstance() {
    if (m_instance == nullptr) {
        m_instance = new Map();
    }
    return m_instance;
}
```

Also, consider using smart pointers.